# is doing mount -t proc none /proc unsecure for a chroot environment?

Tags: centos5, chroot, linux

What does

mount -t proc none /proc

do inside the chrooted environment?

After doing that, when I run htop or ps aux inside the chrooted environment, I can see the actual root's processes.

Does it mean mount -t proc none /proc makes the chroot more insecure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off a **chroot** does not make your system more secure. There are known methods to break out of a chroot that nobody intends to fix because **chroot is not a security mechanism** ([ref](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot)). So your question doesn't really make much sense.

In any case.  Try doing an `ls -al /proc/1/cwd/`

Comment: This is what I got (on the actual root):
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root admin 0 Feb 23 19:04 /proc/1/cwd -> /
so what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the trailing slash, in the command.  Try doing a `cd /proc/1/cwd/` instead or in addition to the ls.

Comment: @Zoredache, hmm, I don't think there's an issue with `cwd`. It seems it's only a symlink so in chroot it will list chroot's /. But there are more interesting stuff like `/proc/<pid>/fd/` (and so on), which will make going out of chroot much easier.

Comment: If you look closely, you will notice that you actually see the root filesystem.  Or at least I see the rootfs in my a chroot On both Debian/Ubuntu systems of various vintages.